# Is there a function similar for InvokeScriptAsync in Windows Phone 8, other than InvokeScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

According to my code execution its Synchronous,ie..my JS Invokescript() function waits for the other executing JS functions to get completed.So I need to execute my InvokeScript function asynchronously for javascript.

Please check the below code.

Function Call from JS File

```
Bridge_Windows.netStatus = function() {
    Bridge_Windows.result = null;
    window.external.notify("function=netStatus&callback=" + function (response) {
        Bridge_Windows.result = response;
    });
    while (Bridge_Windows.result == null) {
       Bridge_Windows.timer = setInterval(function () {
            clearInterval(Bridge_Windows.timer);
            Bridge_Windows.timer = null;
        }, 50);
    }
    return Bridge_Windows.result;
};
```

XAML File

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="orderWebView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Height="768"  IsScriptEnabled="True" ScriptNotify="orderPageScriptNotify" IsGeolocationEnabled="True" Foreground="{x:Null}"/>
```

CS File

```
private void orderPageScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
       string responseJsNotify = null;
        try
        {
            string []aa = e.Value.Split('&');
            string[] bb = aa[0].Split('=');
            responseJsNotify = jsNativeMethodCall(bb[1]);
            MessageBox.Show(responseJsNotify);
            string[] args = { "var "+aa[1]+";callback("+responseJsNotify.ToLower()+");" };
            orderWebView.InvokeScript("eval", args);
        }
        catch(Exception ee) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to make

```
orderWebView.InvokeScript("eval", args);
```

as asynchronous call?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can also use InvokeScriptAsync. Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx

Furthermore you can also wrap your call within a settimeout javascript call which is then executed asynchronously within the Javascript framework. The example below is using a delay of 0 seconds which will start it immediatly (but asynchronously).

```
setTimeout((function() {<do whatever you wanted to do>})(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks in advance,
InvokeScriptAsync can be only used in windows phone 8.1. I need an alternative function for InvokeScriptAsync or any other way for implementing the same in Windows phone 8.

Comment: In that case you can still use setTimeout around your Javascript code to get it executed asynchronously within the Javascript stack.

Comment: I have used setTimeout/setTimeInterval function for the above mentioned purpose, but the InvokeScript function is waiting for the completion of other functions executing in the JS file.